# How to assign hour information to a Pandas Timestamp series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas Timestamp series.
I also have a datetime.time series.
I just want to change the clock part of the timestamp. and I will get these values ​​from the datetime.time series.
What is the easiest way to do this?

**A code like this gives me the result I want:**

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    result= df.date[i].replace(hour=df.time[i].hour,minute=df.time[i].minute,second=df.time[i].second)
    print(result)
```

```
2018-09-06 18:00:00
2018-09-06 18:00:01
2018-09-06 18:00:02
2018-09-06 18:00:03
2018-09-06 18:00:04
```

**Data-related information:**

```py
>>>df
```

Output:

```
|   | time     | date       |
|---|----------|------------|
| 0 | 18:00:00 | 2018-09-06 |
| 1 | 18:00:01 | 2018-09-06 |
| 2 | 18:00:02 | 2018-09-06 |
| 3 | 18:00:03 | 2018-09-06 |
| 4 | 18:00:04 | 2018-09-06 |
```

```py
>>>df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
time            object
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```py
>>>df.date[0]
>>>df.time[0]
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2018-09-06 00:00:00')
datetime.time(18, 0)
```

**But are there such easy methods?**

```
df.date.Example_Function(df.time)
```

or

```
df.date.time=df.time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and because python times also convert to strings:

```
df['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('time').astype(str))
print (df)
                 date
0 2018-09-06 18:00:00
1 2018-09-06 18:00:01
2 2018-09-06 18:00:02
3 2018-09-06 18:00:03
4 2018-09-06 18:00:04
```

Comment: @UğurEren - yop, also is removed column `time`, so not necessary removed later ;)